# using variable in if, elif statement

Tags: python

I was wondering if using variable in if statement can be done. My code is very long and I want to make it short using variable and if statement. Please see code below. I am running code on Ubuntu.

```
number = "" #can be any number
button = "" #1 or 0

if (number == '%s' and button == 1 % (number)):
    print "something"
elif (number == '%s' and button == 0 % (number)):
    print "something"
```

It doesn't get the number variable, I think i am missing something or it's not possible?

my code up to any any desired if's and elif:

```
number = "" #can be any number
button = "" #1 or 0

if (number == 1 and button == 1):
    print "something +1"
elif (number == 1 and button == 0):
    print "something -1"

if (number == 2 and button == 1):
    print "something +2"
elif (number == 2 and button == 0):
    print "something -2"

if (number == 3 and button == 1):
    print "something +3"
elif (number == 3 and button == 0):
    print "something -3"
```

I was hoping i could get this to a shorter code rather than copy and paste the same if/elif's.

Comment: This isn't going to work either way because `number == number`. All the string formatter would do is convert it to a string anyway. It's not clear to me how you want this to work.

Comment: It's unclear to me what you're asking.

Comment: you should clarify more what you're trying to achieve since your code seems wrong on many levels

Comment: Also, `0 % number` will always be `0`, and `1 % number` will always be `1`. There is no point in checking that

Comment: @DeepSpace from what I can discern, that's not intended to be modulo but rather part of the old-style string formatting applied to `number == '%s'`

Comment: @DeepSpace 1% negative number will be 0 and 1 %0 will throw exception

Comment: @ArnonRotem-Gal-Oz Actually, As far as I know, negative right argument for modulus is undefined and is considered implementation details. `1 % number` if `number` is negative will not be `0`. In Python 3.7 it is `number + 1`

Comment: @DeepSpace - right but still it won't always be "1" :)

Comment: hi guys, just edited my post. this is a school project with the kids, was wondering if this is possible? i want to shorten the codes

Comment: I don't think it's possible to reduce this code, but what you could probably do is to change the way you solve your problem. Without the explanation of what you're code is supposed to do it's a bit difficult...

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this can easily be shortened, since you just want to print the number all we need to check is the button, like so:

```
if(button == 0):
    print "something -%d" % (number)
elif(button == 1):
    print "something +%d" % (number)
```

The `%d` tells python to expect a series of *digits* to print and the %(number) simply formats the string with what we want to print. I can see you are using python 2 from your print statements, so check [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-examples) for more.

N.B. Specifically you should be using `"something +{}".format(number)` as that is the correct new way to do it, but since you clearly have seen the percentages before I stuck with those.

Let me know if there is anything else I can do for you.

Comment: i need the if statement refer to the variable not the print.

Comment: @nicollette16 I think you have misunderstood the optimisation I have made, try my code and see if it produces the desired output. Because from your question and what you want it seems like it works fine